# Triangulation lines visible in filled mesh after printing in matlab

Tags: matlab, printing, rendering, matlab-figure, triangulation

I've been using [violin](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45134-violin-plot) to generate (so-called) violin plots in matlab. The plot looks fine:
[image: screenshot from the figure]

However, printing it (both to pdf and svg) results in a file where triangulation lines are visible (zoomed-in to make the point): 
[image: screenshot from pdf]

I guess this is some kind of problem with the zbuffer settings of those lines or something. Under the hood `violin` just uses `fill()` in a way which seems perfectly legit:

```
 h(i)=fill([F(:,i)+i;flipud(i-F(:,i))],[U(:,i);flipud(U(:,i))],fc,'FaceAlpha',alp,'EdgeColor',lc);
```

Replacing `fill` with `patch` does not solve the problem!
A minimal, complete and verifiable example:

```
a=randn(10000,1);
[f, u, bb]=ksdensity(a,'bandwidth',0.2);
figure; fill([f'+i;flipud(i-f')],[u';flipud(u')],'b','FaceAlpha',1);
print(gcf,'-dpdf','a.pdf'); % bad
print(gcf,'-dsvg','a.svg'); % bad
figure; patch([f'+i;flipud(i-f')],[u';flipud(u')],'b','FaceAlpha',1);
print(gcf,'-dpdf','b.pdf'); % bad
print(gcf,'-dsvg','b.svg'); % bad
```

The result:
[image: result of the minimal example]

My version is R2017a.

Comment: What happens if you just set the edge colour the same as the fill colour?

Comment: Or set the 'EdgeColor' to 'none'. Also, try a different renderer. Finally, what process are you using to print to pdf? Can you print to png first then convert to pdf external to matlab? It appears you have some FaceAlpha that's not 1. Try forcing that to one. You may have to grab the handle graphic either from `violin` or from the axes.children.

Comment: @Wolfie: setting the edge color to be the same as the fill one does not help, the triangulation lines are not of the edge color (see the rightmost violin)

Comment: @Wick alpha is 1, and I use prind -dpdf to save as vector graphics pdf. I don't think there is an alternative to that (saving as image is not an option, I need a vector format).

Comment: svg is another vector alternative (so is epsc2 but that should be the same as PDF). It's hard to say from the linked images, but it appears the edges of the faces aren't lining up and you're actually having the background color come through rather than edge color on the facets. Are the figures symmetric left-right? Can you print the vertically-mirrored image over top of the original?

Comment: @Wick I just use built-in fill, how can I do it with a single patch?

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you on?

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: `patch(x,y,c)` Just grab the (x,y) points from your output from violin. Fill creates patch objects, but the way that figure is being generated, it's a bunch of triangles. A single patch object is a polygon. SVG elements can certainly have more than 3 sides. I assume Postscript (and hence PDF) objects can too. If you don't have a nice outline or if it's not ordered, you can consider using the `convexHull` of a `delaunayTriangulation` of your points.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: matlab version is R2017a

Comment: @Wolfie: added minimal complete verifiabe example per your request.

Comment: @Wick can you show how to use patch(x,y,c) to solve the minimal complete verifiable  example?

Comment: @UriCohen I don't have the statistics toolbox. Can you tell me the shape of the variables you wish to print and whether they're in order or not?

Comment: @Wick: it's just a bell shape, any smooth curve will do

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using a patch to create a single polygon representing the outside of a figure.

```
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
r = sqrt(1.125+cos(theta*2));
y = r.*cos(theta);
x = r.*sin(theta);
subplot(121)
plot(x,y);

subplot(122)
h = patch(x,y,'r','edgecolor','none');
```

Comment: It seems the result of patch is just the same! Thank you for your effort anyway :)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Going SVG -> PDF in an external program doesn't help?

Comment: The problem occurs also when printing to SVG (using `print -dsvg`)